# Nearest Neighbor matching with replacement Python

Tags: python, matching, knn, nearest-neighbor

I have 2 dataframes, df_test and df_control. For each element in df_test, I am looking for the closest match in df_control based on a feature_list.

I have seen the NearestNeighbors function in scikit-learn (also [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/206832/matched-pairs-in-python-propensity-score-matching)). However, this function does not have an option for sampling without replacement. Hence, a single element in df_control might be matched with multiple elements in df_test.

If I want to do a "greedy" match, can someone point me to where I should look? R has a package called MatchIt where Nearest Neighbors match does exactly what I want it to do, but I am not able to find it in Python. Thanks in advance.